# Httprequest Postdata response return INCORRECT PASSWORD Error (Netflix Login)

Tags: .net, vb.net

well i have a problem with netflix Login.

I'm trying to make an app (shortcut) to login netflix and use it thrown my app, I know How netflix Cookies working And i know how to handle the auth, So my problem is not in these things!

Well, when i try to login (Postdata) The netflix response return (**INCORRECT PASSWORD**) Even The password is true, and if I send random Username and Random Password It returns (**Can't Find The email**)
Well, Thats mean I have No problem with Cookies and Auth....

So, I used Fiddler browser debugger to Check the connection, but when I tried to login throw the browser while fiddler is on the site is also returns (**INCORRECT PASSWORD**) And when I close fiddler the site returns that the account is working!

IS that about site SSl? I Just need to know where is the problem.

**Note:** If the account working it should returns statuscode 302 in my case always returns 200 with **INCORRECT PASSWORD**

```
Using req As HttpRequest = New HttpRequest()
req.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent
req.AddHeader("cookie", "flwssn=" + flwssn + "; nfvdid=" + nfvdid + "; SecureNetflixId=" + SecureNetflixId + "; NetflixId=v%3D2%26ct" + NetflixId + "; memclid=" + memclid + "; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Tue+Jan+31+2023+02%3A09%3A40+GMT%2B0300&version=202301.1.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=6d05599e-f22f-47e5-95cc-22cc006d4c6e&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false")
req.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
Dim postdata As String = "userLoginId=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&rememberMe=true&flow=websiteSignUp&mode=login&action=loginAction&withFields=rememberMe%2CnextPage%2CuserLoginId%2Cpassword%2CcountryCode%2CcountryIsoCode%2CrecaptchaResponseToken%2CrecaptchaError%2CrecaptchaResponseTime&authURL=" + auth + "&nextPage=&showPassword=&countryCode=%2B49&countryIsoCode=de"
Dim response = req.Post("https://www.netflix.com/de-en/login", postdata, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Dim statuscode = response.statuscode
end using
```

I have tried it in python, php, c# (restclient), vb.net(xnet) have same problem

thanks

Comment: HttpRequest is the representation of a sent request. Perhaps you meant to use httpwebrequest? Mind you, new develooment should use SqlClient ideally. Additionally, I'd recommend testing this in something postman to rule out language nuance and confirm that your structure is correct.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless you can use Httprequest From Xnet.dll, SqlClient is also didn't work :(

Comment: I realize now I typed SQL Client on accident. `HttpClient` was my intent.